# Combine echo and file as input to a command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm testing some upload protocol and want to send, in one line, both the input params as an echo and the file as the upload info.

Example:

```
echo -e 'upload\n<uploadid>\n' | nc 127.0.0.1 1567 < ~/test.txt
```

The problem is that my echo is **ignored** :(

Any idea how to combine both echo and a file as input to a command? (`nc` is just an example)

Note: writing both the echo and the file to another file is not a preferable solution as I'm trying to test a real life scenario of streaming. Duplicating the upload file misses the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one standard input, you cannot pipe and redirect at the same time.

Create the full input, and send that through the pipe:

```
(echo -e 'upload\n<uploadid>\n'; cat ~/test.txt) | nc 127.0.0.1 1567
```

Comment: Depends on the protocol and the recipient. There is nothing in this script which modifies or chokes on arbitrary input. Without more context, we can't tell whether that is a good or a bad thing.

Comment: I'd opt for { echo -e 'upload\n<uploadid>\n'; cat ~/test.txt; } rather than parantheses to prevent creating an unnecessary subshell.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the most efficient way to accomplish this would be to use a here document:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 1567 <<EOF
upload
<uploadid>
$(<test.txt)
EOF
```

This avoids any extra process creation incurred by using a pipeline or calling `cat`.